# Harry Potter fanfiction where Snape loses his memory after the battle and works in a convent

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, severus-snape

I'm looking for a *Harry Potter* fanfiction where Snape loses his memory after the battle and ends up working in a convent as a custodian/herb guy. This is post-war. He is found injured by a lady who's dogsitting for a friend. She who visits him in hospital until he disappears and lives homeless in Scotland. I think Edinburgh? He adopts the name John and gets a job at a convent where a sister of McGonagall lives.

He gets his memory back with Arthur Weasley and Kinglsey Shacklebolt's help. He ends up marrying the lady who found him and visited in hospital. I read it probably two or three years ago. I thought I read it on a03 but I'm having no luck finding it there, or on fanfiction.net. Also can't remember the OFC's name, sorry.